# scalaxb error: Method reads's code too large

Tags: xsd, hl7-fhir, scalaxb, sbt-scalaxb

I'm using scalaxb with scalaxb-sbt to generate the hl7 FHIR specification classes from the [provided XSD files](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/downloads.html).

I get the following errors:

```
[error] Could not write class hl7/org/fhir/XMLProtocol$DefaultHl7orgfhir_BackboneElementableFormat because it exceeds JVM code size limits. Method reads's too large!
[error] Could not write class hl7/org/fhir/XMLProtocol$DefaultHl7orgfhir_ElementableFormat because it exceeds JVM code size limits. Method reads's code too large!
```

Is there a way to tell scalaxb that methods should be broken up upon reaching this limit?